# Convert string column with separated comma to add index

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: ]]

Example on picture in above I want to select column no polis from **358733, 358744, 358745** to **358733 1, 358744 2, 358745 3**

Comment: Try to post your data schema and not only picture. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You would first run `ALTER TABLE` statement to add another column of your preferred type ( https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alter-table-add-column/ ) and then another statement that queries your table, splits the column, and updates the respective column. You should also backup the original table.